# Promise example on Stackoverflow documentation

Tags: javascript, promise

Was going through the first example on Promise mentioned in the documentation

```js
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 var result = 1;

 // This could also be a web request, or anything else either synchronous or asynchronous
 setTimeout(function() {
  result += 10;

  resolve(result);
 }, 1000);

 document.body.addEventListener("click", function clickHandler() {
  document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  reject("You clicked");
 });

 document.body.innerText = "Working... Click anywhere to reject the promise with an error.";
});

promise.then(function(value) {
 document.body.innerText = "Everything went fine! The Promise resolved with: " + value;
}).catch(function(error) {
 document.body.innerText = "Something went wrong: " + error;
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Why is this statement required and what effect it will have on the `Promise` if not present??Why there's a need the remove the listener?

```
document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: It makes sure that the click is registered only once.

Comment: what change it will have it clicked twice...Please specify if any..

Comment: what happens if reject is called twice...

Comment: The value from the first call to resolve or reject becomes the value or error of the promise all further calls are ignored.

Comment: then why there's the need to remove click  listener...

Comment: Because it is a good habit to avoid useless function calls and allow the garbage collector to free the memory used by the promise constructor callback.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The code would still work without this line:

```
 document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

The difference would be that a second click would still invoke the *clickHandler* function which would call the *reject* function for the second time. However, promises ignore calls to *reject* and *resolve* once they are fulfilled, so a second click has no effect.

Still, it is wise to remove listeners when they are no longer of practical use:

- It will avoid that performance degrades. The useless code will no longer be executed and thus not delay the execution of any other (but useful) listeners that might be bound to the same event. If also libraries would leave unused listeners attached to a multitude of elements, or loops would repeatedly bind a listener to an element, things could get out of hand in terms of responsiveness.
- Memory allocated to the closure created by the promise constructor callback can be freed by the garbage collector. As long as a listener is bound to the click event, not only that event handler, but also the context that provides the *reject* function reference, need to be maintained in memory. This is even true if the *promise* variable goes out of scope. Once -- and only when -- the event listener is removed, no more references exist to the event handler nor the *reject* function, and so the memory can be freed. If then the *promise* variable is no longer referenced, the whole promise can be garbage collected as well.

Comment: +1, though it is possible that `reject` does not contain a reference to `promise` after the resolution, if the promise library is implemented well ([example](https://github.com/bergus/creed/blob/911c1d0462fc0468cd377b0f43c48ba0e88f056a/src/Promise.js#L616)). Only the function object itself is leaked then.